# Pulling values from multiple private inner classes with another Event Listener

Tags: java, swing

I have two combo boxes and a calculate button. I want to write if statements for both the combo boxes but have the calculate button pull their values and show the result. How do I pull information from these two private inner classes for the combo boxes.

```
   private class CalculateButtonListener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         int dormCost = 0;
         int totalCost = 0;
         String dormInput = (String) dormsBox.getSelectedItem();
         String mealPlanInput = (String) mealPlansBox.getSelectedItem();
         if(dormInput.equals("Allen Hall")){
            dormCost = 1500;
         } else if(dormInput.equals("Pike Hall")){
            dormCost = 1600;
         } else if(dormInput.equals("Farthing Hall")){
            dormCost = 1200;
         } else if(dormInput.equals("University Suites")){
            dormCost = 1800;
         }
//
//         if(mealPlanInput.equals("7 meals per week")){
//            totalCost = dormCost + 560;
//         } else if(mealPlanInput.equals("14 meals per week")){
//            totalCost = dormCost + 1095;
//         } else if(mealPlanInput.equals("Unlimited Meals")){
//            totalCost = dormCost + 1500;
//         }
```

I want the private inner class of the calculate button to pull the results from the private inner classes of the combo boxes.

Comment: One approach might be to use a model, which is shared between the classes.  So the combo boxes would update the model (and the model would validate these changes) and the button would then take the values from the model to perform it's operations.  This decouples your code, as the only aspect which all the classes rely on is the model, the other classes could change the way they work without adversely affecting everything else ... sweet

Comment: Just bung `dormCost` and `mealPlanCost` fields into the enclosing class.